# How do I tell the Closure javascript compiler to not obfuscate the names of methods of webkitAudioContext?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I use the `webkitAudioContext` constructor, which is native to webkit browsers, in my application written using Google Closure javascript.

After I compiled my javascript using Plovr in ADVANCED mode, I found that the `decodeAudioData` method of my `webkitAudioContext` object was renamed to the obfuscated term `c`. To be concete,

Before compilation:

```
var myAudioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
myAudioContext.decodeAudioData(fileData, myCallBackFunction);
```

After compilation:

```
(new webkitAudioContext).c(a,b);
```

How do I tell the Closure javascript compiler to not obfuscate the names of methods of webkitAudioContext? I have tried to call

```
goog.exportSymbol('webkitAudioContext.prototype.decodeAudioData', webkitAudioContext.prototype.decodeAudioData);
```

to no avail.

Comment: That's what externs are there for: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) mentioned in his comment, [externs files](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3) are used to prevent renaming externally defined symbols. The Closure Compiler source code has externs files under the following directories:

> **trunk
>
>    |-- [externs](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexterns)
>
>    |-- contrib
>
>         |-- [externs](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcontrib%2Fexterns%253Fstate%253Dclosed)**

The externs file **contrib/externs/[w3c_audio.js](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/contrib/externs/w3c_audio.js)** includes `webkitAudioContext`.

See the plovr **[externs](http://plovr.com/options.html#externs)** config option.

Comment: Currently, experimental w3 apis are not included in the default externs. They are usually allowed time to stabilize before moving to the default externs. Most of them can be found in the contrib folder as Chris mentioned. However, it's not unusual to discover missing properties or methods that have been added/changed since the last refresh of the file.

Comment: Thanks! Specifying `"externs": "//chrome_extensions.js",` in my config.js file works. However, specifying `"externs": "//w3c_audio.js,"` in my config file does not work, even if I manually download and add "w3c_audio.js" into the `contrib/externs` folder. Do I need to edit settings somewhere else?

Comment: Specifying `"externs": "//w3c_audio.js"` does not work because the February 2012 plovr release comes bundled with Closure Compiler revision 1559 from February 2, 2012, which did not include `w3c_audio.js`. You need to specify the path to your local copy of `w3c_audio.js` in your plovr config.